# How to make an action in redux/toolkit with rating component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Main problem: I want to send date to the store, but I achieve it only partially, because ranks is sending null or undefined.

```
      const [ranking, setRanking] = useState<number | null>(2);
      const RankHandler = (item, ranking) => {
 
        dispatch(
         rankAdd({
            id: item.id,
           rank: ranking
        })
          
        );
      };



<Rating
  name="simple-controlled"
  value={ranking}
  onClick={(event, newValue) => {
    setRanking(newValue);
    console.log("rating", ranking);
    RankHandler(props.id)
  }}
/>
```

I get an error that I change from controlled to uncontrolled state and this is big issue etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have some variable naming duplication, and by the time you calling the RankHandler it is not guaranteed that the state has been updated. What you can do is pass the new value to the RankHandler itself. Furthermore I would suggest to rename the parameter name from `ranking` to `updatedRanking` or something like that.

And I have little confusion regarding the `props.id`, you are passing it to the RankHandler and inside the RankHandler you are again taking its `id` as well. So it would be `props.id.id`. Please make sure it is the right value or not. Since you have only added this part of the code, I can't comment on that.

And for the `console.log("rating", ranking)`, it won't be showing the updated state since by the time `console.log()` is printed state is not updated.

I hope you got it, let me know if you have any issues.

```
const [ranking, setRanking] = useState<number | null>(2);
const RankHandler = (item, updatedRanking) => {
  dispatch(
    rankAdd({
      id: item.id,
      rank: updatedRanking
    })

  );
};



<Rating
  name="simple-controlled"
  value={ranking}
  onClick={(event, newValue) => {
    setRanking(newValue);
    console.log("rating", ranking);
    RankHandler(props.id, newValue)
  }}
/>
```